# Customize Autocomplete CSS when value is present in the TextField in React Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React Material Autocomplete fields in my project that has a nested TextField. I've currently applied standard styles to it (when no value is present and just the label is showing in the field), and also different styles on hover. However, I want the same hover styles to be applied to the whole Autocomplete box (not just the TextField element) if the TextField has a value in it, but I'm unable to figure out how to do this. My Autocomplete code and current CSS styles are below. Please could anybody help and let me know how I can do this?

**Autocomplete Code**

```
const renderComponentList = (componentList, isDisabled, name, label) => (
    componentList &&
    <Autocomplete
        classes={{
            root: classes.root,
        }}
        options={componentList}
        disabled={isDisabled}
        name={name}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
        onChange={
            (event, value, reason) => {
                this.handleAutocompleteChange(name, value);
            }
        }
        style={{width: '100%'}}
        renderInput={
            (params) =>
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    name={name}
                    label={label}
                    variant="outlined"
                />
        }
    />
);
```

**CSS Styles**

```
export const styles = theme => ({
    // Autocomplete option styles
    root: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        backgroundColor: '#303039',
        opacity: 0.6,
        "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: '#1E1E24',
            borderRadius: '5px',
            opacity: 1,
        },
        "&:focus-within": {
            backgroundColor: '#1E1E24',
            borderRadius: '5px',
            opacity: 1,
        },
        // Something like this to style the autocomplete when input has a value, but this only
        // targets the input field (TextField) rather than the whole Autocomplete field
        // "& input[value]:not([value=''])": {
        //     backgroundColor: '#1E1E24',
        //     borderRadius: '5px',
        //     opacity: 1,
        // },
        "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
            border: '1px solid #484850',
        },
        "&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
            border: '1px solid #484850',
        },
        "&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
            border: '1px solid #484850',
            borderRadius: '5px 5px 0 0',
        },
        "& .MuiInputLabel-outlined": {
            color: '#FFFFFF',
        },
        "& .Mui-disabled": {
            opacity: 0.6,
        },
        "& .Mui-disabled .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
            border: '1px solid #484850',
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately not at the moment. I haven't deployed it yet, it's only running in the test environment. How would I go about creating an online demo for a React project without deploying the full project?

Comment: @SunnyHebbar use codepen

Comment: @keikai Sorry for the confusion, I probably could have worded it a better. All I want to do is apply the `backgroundColor: '#1E1E24',` style to the Autocomplete element (not just the TextField element) when a value is selected and the field is no longer in focus

Comment: @keikai Would that work in a class component? I'm not using Redux or hooks, just plain React with the state declared in the constructor. If it will work then I'm up for giving it a go

Comment: @keikai The way my project is currently configured, I've declared the styles in the styles const in a separate file. I've then imported it into my component file and used the `withStyles` HOC to give my component access to the styles - by declaring `export default withStyles(styles)(SelectForm);` at the bottom of the component file. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to resolve the issue. I had to create a new class for the desired style when a value was present and conditionally render it in the Autcomplete element, based on the relevant state.

To conditionally render the class, I had to pass in `stateVal` as one of the props in my function and then change the `root` line in the Autocomplete classes property to `root: stateVal ? classes.rootHasVal : classes.rootHasNoVal,` instead.

Comment: Are you able to show an example of how you did this, please?